# MVC3 Display search result on the current view (without any new view created)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, search, view

I am pulling some data from a databse and displying it in a list like in [this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). I want to implement a search on the top of the page to search the value of the data reurned on the page. [This example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4) creates a new view for the search page. Is it possible to implement a search on the current view without creating a new view for the search results.

I don't mind doing it with a new view, but I am just wondering

Comment: check [this](http://www.elylucas.net/post/Using-a-grid-that-can-sort-page-and-filter-in-AspNet-MVC3e28093Part-1e28093Using-the-WebGrid-WebHelper.aspx) blog post from ElyLucas This performs searching with results returned to the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The view doesn't need to care about what you are doing in the background with the data. It simply displays whatever you are sending to it in a formatted pretty way. Because of this there is certainly nothing wrong with supplying a parameter in a search box and then pushing this to the controller when clicking a search button. The controller will then be doing the requests to your model or repo to filter the data culminating in a  return of your view loaded with the data it has found, exactly as it would on your initial load (just now with less data than it did before). There should be no need to create a totally different view for this, the view is just your template for returned data.

Comment: Since you are redirecting to the same view, that means that the page is refreshed each time and the search is cancelled then? I was wondering how that works. And, are there any cons in doing it this way?

Comment: You can add to your controller another actionresult which your search button points to. This action can take your input search value as a parameter. After this you would then do your filtering and produce your view again but with the filtered data. If you wish you can also supply back your intial search parameter in the output (viewbag might be easiest) and show this on your view so the user knows the search has happened. This method is very similar to the link posted by Karthik.